# Issues when upgrading from ngrx 7 to ngrx 10

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

could someone please help me to resolve this issue; I have upgraded the ngrx version on my Angular app from version 7 to 10, then when I have tried to launch the application i got this error :

```
 Overload 1 of 8, '(mapFn: (state: unknown, props: unknown) => unknown, props?: unknown): (source$: Observable<unknown>) => Observable<unknown>', gave the following error.
Argument of type '"userDetails"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: unknown, props: unknown) => unknown'.


Overload 2 of 8, '(key: never): (source$: Observable<unknown>) => Observable<never>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"userDetails"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

The code were compiled on the Version 7 :

```
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const selectuserDetails = pipe(
  select('userDetails'),
  filter(uds => uds && uds.isFetched)
);
```

What shall i change to fix this issue please, and compile this code on the version 10!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to `select()`. Instead, import you selector and pass that:

```js
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as MySelectors from 'path/to/selectors'

export const selectuserDetails = pipe(
  select(MySelectors.userDetails),
  filter(uds => uds && uds.isFetched)
);
```

Here is the relevant page in the docs:
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: But why my code worked using ngrx 7 and not 10 ?

Comment: @Youssef This section of the docs should help explain: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-store-without-type-generic